# How to upload a file to FTP using SSJS code in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio, cloudpage, ftp

I am looking out for a way to upload a CSV file to FTP using a SSJS code for one of our usecase.
Here is the code that I have,

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");
    var ftp = new FileTransfer();
    ftp.Host = "ftp.example.com"; // Replace with your FTP server's hostname
    ftp.Username = "test123"; // Replace with your FTP server's username
    ftp.Password = "test123"; // Replace with your FTP server's password
    ftp.Protocol = "SFTP";
    ftp.Connect();
    ftp.Put("path/on/local/file.csv","path/on/server");
    ftp.Disconnect();
</script>
```

But it errors when I run in Automation Studio, please could any one correct me? Also is there any other way to upload the file to FTP using SSJS or API call?

Comment: Where is the file, which you want to upload, placed?

Comment: It is placed on the local computer

Comment: How would you expect Automation Studio to be able to access the file specifically on your local machine? There are multiple threads here on SFSE which address the inability of uploading CSV files for use in data imports. Have you looked at [this approach here](https://www.salaparthi.com/2020/08/importing-csv-file-into-data-extension.html) if you want to build a custom solution for uploading data into a data extension?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Yes I tried the solution from this [blog](https://www.salaparthi.com/2020/08/importing-csv-file-into-data-extension.html). It worked but the problem with my use case was that the CSV file is large and may contain 50k records which the solution given in the blog cannot handle (since we are posting the data from page 1 to page 2). Is there any alternative to this ? thanks in advance

Comment: My recommendation will be to do this using a proper SFTP client, or a fully custom solution built outside of SFMC