# Transfer XML API response as file to FTP with SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio, ftp, sftp

Context: I am looking to implement a daily automated import of a product catalog. I can only access the catalog via an API endpoint that cannot be filtered/paginated and gives ±100K rows of XML as response. Given the size of the XML and the lack of native XML handling in SSJS I'm suspecting using [Eliot Harper's solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170754/parse-xml-in-server-side-javascript) is going to cause timeouts in my SSJS activity. I've previously worked with a data extract "convert XML" activity that worked great with large volumes. In this case, the XML structure is also really simple, max 2 levels deep. So my idea is, do the API call to the product feed with an SSJS activity and store the output as a file on the sFTP. Then use data extract to convert the XML to csv and then use an import to import to a DE.

My question now is, how can I place the XML output I get via the API as a file on the FTP? I found [some code snippets](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/393960/how-to-upload-a-file-to-ftp-using-ssjs-code-in-marketing-cloud) that imply it's possible using `new FileTransfer()` but I can't find any documentation on this Class at all. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talked to Adam Spriggs via Slack, according to him it cannot be done -

> You can't interact with the SFTP via API -- it's hosted in an Akamai
> CDN.

Update with alternative solution found by running AMPscript content block in SSJS activity.

Script:

```
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

try {

    var url = 'https://www.exmaple.nl/xxx';
    var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
    var headerValues = ["Basic xxxxxxxx"];
    var response = HTTP.Get(url, headerNames, headerValues);

    Variable.SetValue("@xml", response.Content);
    var ampscriptCode = Platform.Function.ContentBlockByKey("process_XML"); 

 } catch (e) {
    Write(Stringify(e));
 }
</script>
```

AMPscript block:

```
SET @idrows = BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, "/Models/Model/Id", 1)
SET @makerows = BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, "/Models/Model/Make", 1)
SET @modelrows = BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, "/Models/Model/Model", 1)
then loop through one of them (either one) and grab the values
SET @rowcount = RowCount(@idrows)
FOR @i = 1 TO @rowcount DO
    SET @id = Field(Row(@idrows, @i), "Value")
    SET @make = Field(Row(@makerows, @i), "Value")
    SET @model = Field(Row(@modelrows, @i), "Value")
    UpsertDE('Retention_ProductCatalog', 3, 'Id', @Id, 'Make', @Make, 'Model', @Model)
NEXT @i
```

I checked the result and the order of the data is exactly the same for each rowset so it seems to keep that consistent based on the input. Bit of a hack but it’s superfast, script runs in less than a minute rather than timing out after 30 min.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the array/BuildRowSetFromXML/BuildRowSetFromString to InsertData is performant enough to handle 100k+ lines, but if so, you could try and insert one xml line as one row to a DE. If you upload it to a DE with one column, you will not get any unnecessary commas in the file after you data extract + file transfer to SFTP.

Comment: Yeah I actually solved it with running an AMPscript block within the script activity. I had to do some unorthodox stuff but it's working great. I updated my answer with the AMPscript code.